# Adhoc distribution of Windows Phone 8 apps

Tags: windows-phone-8, adhoc, ad-hoc-distribution

I am in process of developing app for windows phone 8. I need the adhoc distribution of my app to all devices within the organization. I don't want to publish it on the market instead i want the installation of app on the devices within the organization.

Do i need to buy another account for adhoc distribution or i can use the same $99 account for adhoc distribution of app.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Well there are multiple ways to distribute apps,

1. Directly via Visual Studio or XAPDeploy (however the device must be developer unlocked, and connected via usb)
2. Via the normal Store/Marketplace
3. Via Store/Marketplace, with "Hide from users browsing or searching the Store" so that only users with the direct link to the store can find the app
4. Via Beta app distribution 
   **edit: beta apps now do not have a 3 month limit anymore. Only restriction is, that you can "only" have 10000 users and each users email must be manually added for them to be able to download the beta**
5. Company app distribution, which is likely what you are looking for. (However this seems to be relatively difficult) More information here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/jj206943(v=vs.105).aspx
6. Edit: I missed this one: Using "[Windows Intune Direct Management for Windows Phone 8 Mobile Devices](http://technet.microsoft.com/library/jj733640.aspx)"

There are no other ways I know of.

Comment: Beta app distribution seems to be the method of choice: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/help/jj215598(v=vs.105).aspx